# Error when closing Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am currently running Visual Studio Team System Development System 2008 on my workstation and receive the following application event log entry:

> Faulting application devenv.exe,
>   version 9.0.30729.1, stamp 488f2b50,
>   faulting module mfc80u.dll, version
>   8.0.50727.762, stamp 45713438, debug? 0, fault address 0x000c33fc.

Has anyone experienced this issue and know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I searched [Google for 0x000c33fc](http://www.google.com/search?q=0x000c33fc) and found many people mentioning this fault address in conjunction with IE and Word. It sounds like it might be a bug in some common Microsoft library.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what that is, but it might be fixed by resetting your VS 2008 settings. See [here.](http://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/archive/2008/06/03/did-you-know-how-to-reset-your-environment-settings-via-tools-import-export-settings-229.aspx)